# How to add ios application on Safari share extension?

Tags: ios, iphone

How can we add our own application on safari extension used for sharing.

Comment: What is the meaning of your question ? U asked the question and gave the answer also. What is your question ?

Comment: Hey Nayak, How can we add our own application on safari extension used for sharing.

Comment: @Ankit Please post an actual question in the body, not in the comment.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser , Thanks for the suggestion . I did it

Comment: Dear @Ankit, welcome to StackOverflow. It is unclear what your problem is.  Please take some time and read instructions on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @PouriaHadjibagheri : ok thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're interested in the so called "Share Extension" which is available starting from iOS 9.

Start from [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1) and then ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks. I will get back to you after understanding the link

Comment: Hey i followed the link and added my application on share extension of safari.But how to apply the webservices for the same.Like facebook use to do.Share the post on a user profile

Comment: I think what you're asking is described in the chapter [Handling Common Scenarios](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1) of the above mentioned reference.

Comment: I had already gone through that chapter but nowhere found that how to pass my extension data to my server.